# "# this is a string", How python identifies it as a string but not a comment?

Tags: python

I really want to know how python identifies # in quotes as a string and normal # as a comment

I mean how the code to identify difference between these actually works, like will the python read a line and how it excludes the string to find the comment

`"# this is a string" # this is a comment`

How the comment is identified, will python exclude the string and if so, How?

How can we write a code which does the same, like to design a compiler for our own language with python

I am a newbie, please help

Comment: because `""` denotes the start and end of a string... a `#` alone is identified as the start of a comment

Comment: Read the first paragraph of the [informal introduction](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/introduction.html#an-informal-introduction-to-python): *Comments in Python start with the hash character, `#`, and extend to the end of the physical line. A comment may appear at the start of a line or following whitespace or code, __but not within a string literal. A hash character within a string literal is just a hash character.__*

Comment: This is quite an advanced topic and you say you are a newbie, so I'm not sure if you really want to dive into it. But if you're really interested, the official Python documentation explains it quite clearly and extensively in [Chapter 2: Lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). String literals (which is what you're question is about) is discussed in section [2.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that whether something is a string or a comment can be determined from just one single character. That is the job of the [scanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (or lexical analyzer if you want to sound fancy).

If it starts with a `"`, it's a string. If it starts with `#`, it's a comment.

In the code that makes up Python *itself*, there's probably a loop that goes something like this:

```
# While there is still source code to read
while not done:
    # Get the current character
    current = source[pos]

    # If the current character is a pound sign
    if current == "#":
        # While we are not at the end of the line
        while current != "\n":
            # Get the next character
            pos += 1
            current = source[pos]
    elif current == '"':
        # Code to read a string omitted for brevity...
    else:
        done = True
```

In the real Python lexer, there are probably dozens more of those if statements, but I hope you have a better idea of how it works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the quotes

```
# This is a comment

x = "# this is a string"

x = '# this is a also string'

x = """# this string 
         spans 
         multiple 
          lines"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"# this is a string" # this is a comment
```

In simple terms, the interpreter sees the first *"*, then it takes everything that follows as part of the string until it finds the matching *"* which terminates the string. Then it sees the subsequent *#* and interprets everything to follow as a comment. The first *#* is ignored because it is between the two quotes, and hence is taken as part of the string.